# Loop with different iterations

Tags: c, loops, logging, embedded, sensors

I'm new to programming. I need a some help.  I have 5 sensors in my data logger. I'm planning to write sensor data to serial flash memory. I'm planning to write each sensor with different sampling rate. For example: pressure = 1Hz, Temp = 2 Hz, humidity = 2Hz, Light = 5Hz and3-axis with 100Hz. 
Hence my loop gonna have different iterations.
How to make a loop which can vary every time? I wrote a function to read each sensor writing frequencies.

like below

```
 char getpressurefreq();
 char getluxfreq();
 char gettempfreq();
 char gethumidityfreq();
 uint16_t getACCfreq();`
```

I kept them in main function. 
Now I have frequency data.
Now I have to make loop according to the above frequencies.

How can I write loop for above inputs? Kindly suggest some solution. thank you all.

Comment: Have you got timers in your application/platform?

Comment: Is it OK to use busy loop?

Comment: This can be achieved using function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already written hardware drivers that provide data to those functions, then the first step would be to create a standard function interface.

You can easily do this by sacrificing a few bytes of stack RAM:

```
typedef uint16_t freq_read_t (void);
```

You should never use `char` to hold integer values anyway, because of its implementation-defined signedness.

Every sensor driver that reads a frequency must now implement a function with the above specified format.

Then in the caller, you can create an array of function pointers:

```
freq_read_t* const freq_read [SENSORS_N] =
{
  getpressurefreq,
  getluxfreq,
  gettempfreq,
  gethumidityfreq,
  getACCfreq,
};
```

(Declare pointer as a constant pointer to data, so it will get stored in NVM)

The loop will turn trivial and be the same no matter function:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<SENSORS_N; i++)
{
  uint16_t freq = freq_read[i]();
  // do something with freq
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are sampling sensor data, you need to configure a timer module to set the base time for your system. As your fastest signal will be sampled with a frequency of 100 Hz, you could use 10 ms time-base.

Normally the timer will fire an interrupt, then in the timer interrupt handler you can write something like this:

```
void TimerInt(void)
{
    static uint32_t ticks = 0;
    ticks++;
    /* sample pressure */
    if ((ticks % 100) == 0)
    {
        read_pressure();
    }
    /* sample temp and humidity*/
    if ((ticks % 50) == 0)
    {
        read_temperature();
        read_humidity();
    }
    /* sample light*/
    if ((ticks % 20) == 0)
    {
        read_light();
    }
    /* sample 3-axis - every time */
    read_3_axis();
}
```

As an alternative and if you dont't have a timer (or you don't want to configure one), you need same way to create a delay function. Then in you main loop you can do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        TimerInt();
        delay(10); /* delay 10 ms */
    }
}
```

PD: It will be helpful if you mention what is the platform you are working on.